# In material-ui version 1.0.0 how to set ../tileData file?

Tags: material-ui

I am using this :- https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/drawers/

but I cant understand how to set ./tileData file which they imported. I think it will array

Can anyone suggest me or post that file

Comment: you are looking for this:https://github.com/mbrookes/material-ui/blob/16c790bd86ebaa629f32358744dc3a0d9634bcc1/docs/src/pages/component-demos/grid-list/tileData.js ?

Comment: Yes I am looking for that. But,Not Exactly like this in this they set one json array and by that they map of this and show grid,, but in my question they simply put an array of json and didn't map or do anythinng they manage how ? -----and thanks buddy

in my question  <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the tileData. You can find it in source code.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/drawers/tileData.js

This link might help you find it if it moves again:

https://www.google.com/search?q=material-ui+docs+demos+src+drawers+tiledata.js+site%3Agithub.com

Comment: The link was broken. I edited to read like this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/drawers/tileData.js